# Uninitialized constant while using gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventbrite

I am trying to run the following code to initialize the official EventbriteClient

```
eb_client = EventbriteClient.new(eb_auth_tokens)
```

however, I faced the *uninitialized constant WelcomeController::EventbriteClient*

I double checked and confirmed gem is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forget to add this gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'EventbriteClient'
```

Comment: when I added this, it says

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tzinfo":
  In Gemfile:
    eventbrite-client (>= 0) ruby depends on
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22) ruby

    rails (= 4.1.8) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.8) ruby depends on
        tzinfo (1.1.0)

and both tzinfo and eventbrite are installed.

Comment: Yes, it is ok. Look at my other answer.